# How to build correct XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, savon

I want to build request like the below:

http://wklej.org/id/1367146/

Hoverer, I cannot build the XML using Savon. Here is how I do it:

```
def get_transactions_ids(options = {})
    options[:items_id_array] ||= []
    options[:user_role] ||= 'seller'
    options[:shipment_id_array] ||= []

    puts options[:items_id_array].inspect

    message = {
        session_handle: @session_handle,
        items_id_array: WebapiHelper.array_to_items_array(options[:items_id_array]),
        user_role: options[:user_role],
        shipment_id_array: options[:shipment_id_array],
    }

    client.call(:do_get_transactions_i_ds, message: message)
end
```

Here is implementation of WebapiHelper.array_to_items_array function

```
def self.array_to_items_array (array)

    result = []

    array.each do |item|
      result.push ({:item => item})
    end

    [result]

end
```

It produces me the following XML http://wklej.org/id/1367149/
It adds extra  tag under  tag.

Comment: what happens if you change `items_id_array` to just `options[:items_id_array]`?

Comment: not clearly understand what you mean. Here is WSDL for it https://webapi.allegro.pl/service.php?wsdl  I try to call doGetTransactionsIDs method.

Comment: You wrote "It adds extra tag under tag" which makes no sense. By comparing XML files I assumed problem is with `<element>` tag, and I guess solution for this is not to call `WebapiHelper.array_to_items_array`

Comment: Please take a look on XML files. It is `<element<tns:item>4227658691</tns:item>` but should be `<tns:item>4227658691</tns:item>`. Does it make sens now?

Comment: When I not call `WebapiHelper.array_to_items_array` method it gives me many `<tns:itemsIdArray>` tags with the value. It should be only one `<tns:itemsIdArray>` but with many `<tns:item>` inside.

Comment: `WebapiHelper.array_to_items_array` gives you an array of hashes and that's where the problem is. Change this line just to `items_id_array: options[:items_id_array],`

Comment: If I change to ` items_id_array: options[:items_id_array]` then it produces http://wklej.org/id/1369144/ which is invalid. Only one `<tns:itemsIdArray>` can be in the document. Inside of `<tns:itemsIdArray>` must be many `<tns:item>`. This is correct file: http://wklej.org/id/1367146/